# Why my input doesn't fit into the div?

Tags: html, css

I wrote this html and css codes:

HTML

```
  <body>
    <div id="container">
      <div id="containerHeader">
        <h1>Seek & enjoy</h1>
        <h3>Your movie seeker</h3>
        <div id="containerForm">
          <form class="form-wrapper cf">
            <div id="inputplusbuttons">
              <input type="text" placeholder="Find your movie" required>
              <div id="containerButtons">
                <button id="seek" type="submit">Seek</button>
                <button id="reset" type="submit">Reset</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="results">
        <p>
        </p>
        <div id="movieList">
        </div>
        <div id="movieDetails">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

I'm trying to fit an input into a div but I'm failing and don't know why (CSS code is on JSFiddFiddle). I reached these two options

1. http://jsfiddle.net/rmkc55zc/
2. http://jsfiddle.net/rmkc55zc/3/

In option 1 input width is 100% but then input is longer than div. 
In option 2 I added `overflow: hidden` but then input is cut and I don't like that.

Does anybody knows something else I can try to fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add [`box-sizing: border-box;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) property to your `input` styles. The [result](http://jsfiddle.net/rmkc55zc/4/embedded/result/).

Comment: Cool. I didn't know that property. Thanks

Comment: @Noob_Number_1 you may need to use browser-specific prefixes to ensure better browser compatibility.