# The input doesn't fit into the div

Tags: html, css

I don't know why the input is overcoming the edge of the div.

I tried this solution (put in my CSS code `box-sizing: border-box;` in the input part) but without success:
[Why my input doesn't fit into the div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27169706/why-my-input-doesnt-fit-into-the-div)

Then I researched in w3schools but they propose the same solution:
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_responsive_form.asp

My code:

```css
html,
body {
  font-size: 15px;
  background: #000000;
  color: #b9b9b9;
  margin: 0;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

input {
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  background: transparent !important;
  color: #535353;
  border: 0.1em solid  !important;
  padding: 0.2rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/********** TYPOGRAPHY START **********/

/* General */
h1,
h2 {
  margin: 0;
  color: #ffffff;
}

/* For classes */
.subtitle {
  font-size: 0.75rem;
  margin: 0;
}

.article-type {
  font-size: 0.85rem;
}

.article-cotinueReading {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #287cd4;
  border: 0.1em solid #287cd4;
  padding: 0.1em;
}

.article-cotinueReading:hover {
  background: #30394a;
}

/**********  TYPOGRAPHY END  **********/


/********** LAYOUT START **********/
.container {
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 900px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.container-flex {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

/* Navegation */
.nav-list {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  justify-content: center;
}

.nav-li {
  margin: 0.75em 0em;
}

.nav-link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #b9b9b9;
  font-weight: 700;
  padding: 0.2em 0;
}

.nav-link:hover {
  color: #287cd4;
  border-bottom: 0.15em solid;
}

/**********  LAYOUT END  **********/
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <title>Proyecto Página Web</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="container container-flex">
      <aside id="aside" role="complementary">

        <div class="site-title">
          <h1>My Web</h1>
          <p class="subtitle">Web about proyects</p>
        </div>

        <div class="container container-nav">
          <nav>
            <ul class="nav-list">
              <li class="nav-li"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Inicio</a></li>
              <li class="nav-li"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Sobre mí</a></li>
              <li class="nav-li"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Proyectos libres que uso</a></li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
        </div> <!-- / .container container-nav -->

        <div class="container container-footer">
                <div class="mb-4">
                    <h3>Suscribete al newsletter</h3>
                    <form action="#" class="form-subscribe">
                        <div class="form-input">
                            <input type="text" id="form-newsletter" placeholder="Introduce tu e-mail">
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>  <!-- / .container container-footer -->
      </aside>

      <main role="main">
        <article class="article-recent">
          <div class="article-recent-main">
            <p class="article-type">Last Proyect</p>
            <h2 class="article-title">Make a Drone</h2>
            <p class="article-body">Text of the articleText of the articleText of the articleText of the articleText of the articleText of the articleText of the articleText of the articleText of the articleText of the articleText of the articleText of the articleText of the articleText of the articleText of the articleText of the articleText of the articleText of the articleText of the articleText of the articleText of the articleText of the articleText of the articleText of the articleText of the article
            </p>
            <a href="#" class="article-cotinueReading">Seguir leyendo</a>
          </div>
          <div class="article-recent-secondary">
            <img src="" alt="" class="article-image">
          </div>
        </article>
      </main>
    </div> <!-- / .container container-flex-->

  </body>
</html>
```

If anyone have fix the same problem or know who to fix it, I appreciate it. 
Thanks for your help.

Comment: if you share your code with us we might be able to help you

Comment: @ppichier
OHH SORRY, I have forgotten to put it

Comment: w3schools is, once again not the best place to go lookup for the best code to use.

Comment: Did you try adding `width: 100%` to an input? Every html input has default styles that make them take up a certain width.

Comment: Ladies and gentlemen we have a winner!!!
Thanks @AntonijaŠimić for taking your time fixing my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply apply `width: 100%` to an input element. Every html element has default styles set by browsers which makes them take up space in a certain way. That is why it goes outside of the container.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty basic example using **[CSS flex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/flex)**:

```css
/*QuickReset*/ * {box-sizing: border-box; margin: 0; font:16px/1.4 sans-serif;}

.Form {}
.Form-label { display: flex; }
.Form-labelDesc { min-width: 200px; }
.Form-field { flex: 1; }    /* Business as usual */
```

```html
<form class="Form" action="">

  <label class="Form-label">
    <span class="Form-labelDesc">&#x1F464;&#xfe0e; Name</span>
    <input class="Form-field" type="text" name="name" autocomplete="off" />
  </label>
  
  <label class="Form-label">
    <span class="Form-labelDesc">&#x1F4e7;&#xfe0e; Email</span>
    <input class="Form-field" type="text" name="email" autocomplete="off" />
  </label>
  
  <label class="Form-label">
    <span class="Form-labelDesc">&#x1F589;&#xfe0e; Bio</span>
    <textarea class="Form-field" name="bio" autocomplete="off"></textarea>
  </label>
  
  <button type="submit">Register</button>
  
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Roko, but the "QuickReset" that you propose don't work for me. I have already tried it following the w3school tutorial.

Comment: @DavidApellido have you clicked the "Run Code Snippet" button under my answer? Yes? Are the Inputs and Textareas aligned? Yes? Well, that was only my proposal before you pasted your code. Also, have you clicked the link in my first paragraph? What have you learned from it? Does w3schools use CSS Flexbox? My suggestion is to put w3schools in your ignore list. They have nothing to do with W3C and they even sell irrelevant certificates.

Comment: I see, i am going to start using MDN
And maybe i don't know how to fix the input, but now i learn how to make a "Run Code Snippet" thanks to you, this will be very useful for future posts :)